# Can we have an SSCCE magic link?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

The [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) guide is `<opinion>`***plain wonderful***`</opinion>`. If the OP has a curious mind, they rapidly get the gist, and a *gimme teh codez* Question becomes an answerable and enjoyable one.

I'm mainly saying in Comments

> Please check the guide http://sscce.org, because etc, etc

I tried `[sscce]` to see if it rendered something, but alas. My suggestion is to implement it and print some meaningful message/phrase/keywords or something. I don't have nothing specific in mind and am mainly throwing this to the Meta lion-esse-s.

Thinking about it, I guess it would have to be a <kbd>[Technology](https://stackexchange.com/sites#technology)</kbd> magic link. Is it possible in the grand magic scheme of things?

---

<sub>Related: [Include SSCCE.ORG contents in an instruction page somewhere](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/201952)</sub>

> [image]

Comment: 1+ I would use this a lot.

Comment: Given the nature of the link (its not hosted by SO), one *might* want to consider poking the appropriate people to add it to the help section so that one doesn't have to worry about external resources and can appropriately tweak it to a SO audience. Then it *should* be auto covered with the `[help/something]` [magic link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92060/add-data-se-style-magic-links-to-comments).

Comment: Related: [Include SSCCE.org contents in an instruction page somewhere](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/201952), and note that [it's included in the "must include valid code" close banner](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188511/questions-must-describe-the-specific-problem-and-include-valid-code-to-reprod).

Comment: @JoshCaswell but one can't link to it directly (its a level of indirection... and just think of how many people have difficulty with pointers).  If it was mirrored, it could be linked as `[help/sscce]`.

Comment: @JoshCaswell, I had the same related in mind (and added to this Q). And also sometimes it's better to copy/paste the close reason in a comment, so the OP has some margin to work the Q out.

Comment: I didn't realize you meant "add it to the Help Center _as its own section_", @MichaelT.

Comment: @JoshCaswell yep.  It might also be helpful to have the [question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist) mirrored in the help center for the same reason... but that would be another wish and another feature request.  Making helpful comments easier to write makes it easier to give them sooner in the process of fixing a poor question.

Comment: Oh look, [a user script](http://pastebin.com/xuRmxENi) - it's an extension of [SE Comment Link Helper](http://stackapps.com/q/2378) (because I already use that) - in addition it just replaces "\[sscce\]" with `[SSCCE](http://sscce.org)`.

Comment: vote to close and move on, when the question is closed the user will be given the close reason that contains the link. Why do we need to comment about it?

Answer (score 3):

I disagree with this, on the grounds that it will promote simply linking to SSCCE as a means to disregard addressing the actual issues with a post.

Remember ["What have you tried?"](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) (["what have you tried,](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172758/what-have-you-tried-epidemic) [what have you tried,](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122986/is-it-ok-to-leave-what-have-you-tried-comments) [what have you tried,](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173348/what-have-you-tried-evasions) [what have you tried...](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172847/is-there-a-new-what-have-you-tried))

That link was eventually blacklisted. Instead of actually addressing the problem with the post, people would link to the post asking: "what have you tried?"

And, let's be honest, SSCCE is pretty much the same thing, albeit in a less caustic tone. I already see it used on many questions where, really, it's not good or relevant advice.

So I ask you: is this really needed? If you'd like to give feedback on a post, use something more clear, and *maybe* link to SSCCE if it's helpful.

Plus, let's be honest, how hard is it to type out the link to SSCCE? It's not like it's hard to remember.

Comment: As far as I can remember, WHYT never entered our FAQ or Close Reasons.

Comment: I don't really see how that's relevant; having a magic link allows people  to simply, well, link to SSCCE instead of expanding on what is wrong with a post. The close reason you have provided explains specifically why the advice in SSCCE is useful.

Comment: Gee, I want to explain what's wrong with the post, and for that I have [ask] -`[ask]`, [answer] -`[answer]`, [help/on-topic] -`[help/on-topic]`, and ***Pretty, please, provide a Short Compilable Example***.

Comment: I think this would make it too easy for people to _default_ to SSCCE as a link reference, in the same way that WHYT did. The point is that SSCCE is an _addendum_ to the post, not the _main content,_ and we should do everything to keep it that way.

Comment: Let's see `http://sscce.org` (16) versus `[sscce]` (7+some-meaningful-content)

Comment: Is it really necessary to save seven characters?

Comment: That's what magic is for, no? :)

Comment: The magic links are for links which are hard or irritating to remember. SSCCE is not one of those.

Comment: Ok. We're in disagreement, then.

Comment: I ought to think that they should take the information from SSCCE and place it into their own help centre page.

Comment: @brasofilo Worse yet, I do `[SSCCE](http://sscce.org)`, so that's 18 characters more (though I often open another tab and let Chrome auto-complete do some of the work). I do this because "an sscce.org" doesn't make too much sense (sscce.org is a website, SSCCE is a thing). If we're going by key presses, that's 7 VS 29.

Comment: Note that "\[sscce\]" is not long enough for a comment, but "`http://sscce.org`" or "`[SSCCE](http://sscce.org)`" is (where-as "What have you tried?" (or `http://whathaveyoutried.com`) is long enough). So, with a magic link, you have to add at least **something** else (though I haven't seen ((m)any?) comments consisting exclusively of the link). If anything, ban references to "SSCCE" without a link, or short comments containing "SSCCE", but being against the magic link doesn't make *too* much sense.

Comment: As a technicality, the link itself isn't blocked, just comments consisting exclusively of "What have you tried?" or the link, unless this changed recently.

Comment: @Duke I'm not sure, but I think it's comments containing the text and/or link.